# How to setup vuex and vue-router to redirect when a store value is not set?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex, feathersjs

I'm working with the latest versions of vue-router, vuex and feathers-vuex and I have a problem with my router.

What I'm doing is to check if a route has the property `"requiresAuth": true` in the meta.json file. If it does then check the value of `store.state.auth.user` provided by feathers-vuex, if this value is not set then redirect to login.

This works fine except when I'm logged in and if I reload my protected page called `/private` then it gets redirected to login so it seems that the value of `store.state.auth.user` is not ready inside `router.beforeEach`.

So how can I set up my router in order to get the value of the store at the right moment?

My files are as follow:

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import store from '../store'

const meta = require('./meta.json')

// Route helper function for lazy loading
function route (path, view) {
  return {
    path: path,
    meta: meta[path],
    component: () => import(`../components/${view}`)
  }
}

Vue.use(Router)

export function createRouter () {
  const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ y: 0 }),
    routes: [
      route('/login', 'Login')
      route('/private', 'Private'),
      { path: '*', redirect: '/' }
    ]
  })

  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
      if (!store.state.auth.user) {
        next('/login')
      } else {
        next()
      }
    } else {
      next()
    }
  })

  return router
}
```

meta.json

```
{
  "/private": {
    "requiresAuth": true
  }
}
```

Comment: you should provide initiate action which will prepare store for the first loading

Comment: you know about https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html? so you can define the requiresAuth on the routes themselves
regarding the store, I'm handling the whole login logic in Login.vue, which also sets the user in the store, uh but I don't have a /login route, I'm loading Login.vue conditionally instead of the requested component if user.id is missing, this way login is automatically showing regardless of url if user is not logged in and won't need to redirect on successfull login..maybe this helps

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by returning a promise from vuex action and then run the validations

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  store.dispatch('auth/authenticate').then(response => {
    next()
  }).catch(error => {
    if (!error.message.includes('Could not find stored JWT')) {
      console.log('Authentication error', error)
    }
    (to.meta.requiresAuth) ? next('/inicio-sesion') : next()
  })
})
```